# Compilation error of VS2010 Express Edition together with QT4.7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, build

Hallo,
I would like to use Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition together with QT4.7 to continue the development of a project that using QT 4.6 and Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition.

I was using custom build in my project. Below is the Post-Build Event > Command line property:

```
mt.exe -manifest "C:\Development\Tool\MyProgram\Manifest\x86_5063_$(ConfigurationName)\generic.manifest" -outputresource:"$(TargetPath)";
```

When I'm trying to build the project, I got this error:

```
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The command "mt.exe -manifest "C:\Development\Tool\MyProgram\Manifest\x86_5063_Debug\generic.manifest" -outputresource:"C:\Development\Src\Cpp\MyProgram\Debug\MyProgram.exe"
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 31.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is there any guideline on this?

THanks @!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the limited info provided.  Did you add the runtime to the config file?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxgeneralprerelease/thread/406a9a61-1904-44f7-bc05-d809d78e7938/

Comment: Thanks on your comment, I have put in more description in to my problem. Hope this could give some real picture to you.